# Match a pattern after a pattern?

Tags: regex

Can you match a pattern in text that occurs after a pattern for instance in:

```
ssasabafra
```

Match all the a's after the b? Ive tried using a look behind like so:

```
(?<=b)[a]+
```

But it only matches the first `a` is there a way to match all occurences after `b`?

Comment: "Match all the a's after the b?" .. `"b(a*)"` ?

Comment: Do you just want to count all the 'a's after a 'b'?

Comment: If you ONLY want to pull out the `a`s after the occurrence of `b`, this is probably best suited to an actual programming language where you can find the instance of `b` and match on anything thereafter. It would just be easier.

Comment: Yeah sorry just the a's after the b

Comment: What about? (?<=b)([^a]*(a)[^a]*)* Your match fails after the first 'a' because you restrict your regex to only allow 'a'-s

Comment: I assume you want to actually *match* just the `a`s, and not simply capture them

Comment: Sorry but i dont know what you mean. Can you explain me the difference between matching and capturing. I mean i know whats the main difference but how does it affect this problem, and why you said "simply capture" instead of "match"?

Comment: If you want to capture the `a`s (to count them for example), you could do something like `b(?:.*?(a))*`

Comment: It's matching/capturing only the first 'a', and i still dont know what difference you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an expression engine that allows repetition in lookbehind expressions, how about:

```
(?<=b.*?)a
```

This looks behind for a `b` followed by any number of characters, and matches `a`

---

For most regex engines however, I don't think this is possible. But, what you *can* do is split the string on `b`, match the second part with `/a/`, then join the two strings again with `b`.

Comment: This will also match only first `a`. OP wants all the occurrences.

Comment: @RohitJain: No, it doesn't. This is the correct answer (although it does presuppose a .NET or JGSoft regex engine).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
a(?=[^b]*$)
```

However, this doesn't make sure that there is some `b` before the `a`. I guess you want to match all the `a` that is not followed by some substring containing `b`.

See demo on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=a%28?=%5B%5Eb%5D%2a%24%29&input=ssasabafra)

If you want to make sure that, there must be `b` somewhere before the `a`, then you should probably use the string manipulating functions, in your particular programming language.